# Is it possible to make a foreach loop for every character in a string?

Tags: tcl

I want to make a foreach loop for every character in a string.

I've tried using just `foreach`, but that will only loop once before breaking.
for example:

```
set string "a string"
foreach character $string {                   
    puts "a character was counted"
}
```

I expect that the code above will do `puts "a character was counted"` 8 times (for every character in "a string"), but it only does `puts "a character was counted"` once

Comment: I'd expect the loop as written to run twice, as `a string` is valid syntax for a two element list (first element `a`, second element `string`). But apart from that…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to explicitly break the string into a list of characters:

```
foreach char [split $string ""] {...
```